# was not arrogant and

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation, negation

> a. He was not arrogant and helpful.
>
> b. He was not arrogant, and helpful.
>
> c. He was not arrogant and very helpful.
>
> d. He was not arrogant, and very helpful.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct and correctly punctuated?

The 'not' is supposed to modify 'arrogant' only.

I think (b) and (d) work but the other two don't.

Comment: A sentence can be grammatical but still not make sense. Yours read oddly because of the combination of adjectives. I would suggest "He was not arrogant, but (very) helpful," or "He was not at all arrogant - in fact, he was very helpful."

Comment: With or without the adverb "very" this question is asking if the addition or omission of a comma is the difference between a sentence being  grammatical **or** not. It's not. Punctuation is important **but** only in tests and formal writing. Good grammar depends on syntax **and** semantics.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, **was not** modifies both arrogant and helpful. So, all of these mean that he **was not** helpful. The commas don't help here at all.

You can avoid this easily by changing the construction.

> He was helpful and not arrogant.
>
> He was not arrogant, but helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> a. He was not arrogant and helpful.

> b. He was not arrogant, and helpful.

> c. He was not arrogant and very helpful.

> d. He was not arrogant, and very helpful.

From context, these examples can be interpreted and rephrased as

> a. He was not arrogant and [*was*] helpful.

> b. He was not arrogant, [*sic*] and [*was*] helpful.

> c. He was not arrogant and [*was*] very helpful.

> d. He was not arrogant, [*sic*] and [*was*] very helpful.

To avoid ambiguity, *was* should be inserted into examples (a) and (c), and the examples would be fine.

Examples (b) and (d), with their commas, are not fine; we should not use comma when connecting two phrases with a coordinating conjunction.

Comment: Note that, when using the verb **insert**, the thing that is inserted is the object of the verb, and the thing that it is inserted into is attached with the preposition **into**. In a passive voice sentence, the object becomes the patient and appears before the verb, rather than after the preposition **with**. Your last-but-one sentence should therefore read "To avoid ambiguity, **was** should be inserted **into** examples a and c.*